# Prevent auto-sized TableLayoutPanel row from collapsing when content is invisible

Tags: vb.net, winforms, visible, autosize, tablelayoutpanel

My problem is a simple one.  I have a `TableLayoutPanel`, with various rows in it, each containing controls.

I want the `TableLayoutPanel` to auto-size itself based on its content, EXCEPT when a control has its `Visible` property set to `False`.

When this happens, I want to keep the blank space where the row is.

Currently, when a control's `Visible` property is set to `False`, the row it is on collapses.  If I check the debugger, I can see that the control's `Height` is still `24`, not `0`.

I've been playing around with different settings to no avail, and Googling the problem only seems to find people asking about how to achieve the exact opposite of what I'm trying to do.

Full code for the simple example is below:

> Form1.vb

```
Option Strict On
Option Explicit On
Option Infer Off

Public Class Form1
    Private Sub Form1_Load( sender As Object,  e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        For i As Integer = 0 To 2
            Dim c As New CheckBox()
            c.Text = "Checkbox" & i+1

            If i = 0
                AddHandler c.CheckedChanged,    Sub(sender2 As Object, e2 As EventArgs)
                                                    If TryCast(sender2, CheckBox).Checked
                                                        TryCast(TableLayoutPanel1.Controls(1), CheckBox).Visible = False
                                                    Else
                                                        TryCast(TableLayoutPanel1.Controls(1), CheckBox).Visible = True
                                                    End If
                                                End Sub
            End If

            TableLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(c)
        Next
    End Sub
End Class
```

> Form1.Designer.vb

```
<Global.Microsoft.VisualBasic.CompilerServices.DesignerGenerated()> _
Partial Class Form1
    Inherits System.Windows.Forms.Form

    'Form overrides dispose to clean up the component list.
    <System.Diagnostics.DebuggerNonUserCode()> _
    Protected Overrides Sub Dispose(ByVal disposing As Boolean)
        Try
            If disposing AndAlso components IsNot Nothing Then
                components.Dispose()
            End If
        Finally
            MyBase.Dispose(disposing)
        End Try
    End Sub

    'Required by the Windows Form Designer
    Private components As System.ComponentModel.IContainer

    'NOTE: The following procedure is required by the Windows Form Designer
    'It can be modified using the Windows Form Designer.  
    'Do not modify it using the code editor.
    <System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThrough()> _
    Private Sub InitializeComponent()
        Me.TableLayoutPanel1 = New System.Windows.Forms.TableLayoutPanel()
        Me.SuspendLayout
        '
        'TableLayoutPanel1
        '
        Me.TableLayoutPanel1.AutoSize = true
        Me.TableLayoutPanel1.AutoSizeMode = System.Windows.Forms.AutoSizeMode.GrowAndShrink
        Me.TableLayoutPanel1.ColumnCount = 1
        Me.TableLayoutPanel1.ColumnStyles.Add(New System.Windows.Forms.ColumnStyle())
        Me.TableLayoutPanel1.Location = New System.Drawing.Point(13, 13)
        Me.TableLayoutPanel1.Name = "TableLayoutPanel1"
        Me.TableLayoutPanel1.RowCount = 3
        Me.TableLayoutPanel1.RowStyles.Add(New System.Windows.Forms.RowStyle())
        Me.TableLayoutPanel1.RowStyles.Add(New System.Windows.Forms.RowStyle())
        Me.TableLayoutPanel1.RowStyles.Add(New System.Windows.Forms.RowStyle())
        Me.TableLayoutPanel1.Size = New System.Drawing.Size(0, 0)
        Me.TableLayoutPanel1.TabIndex = 0
        '
        'Form1
        '
        Me.AutoScaleDimensions = New System.Drawing.SizeF(6!, 13!)
        Me.AutoScaleMode = System.Windows.Forms.AutoScaleMode.Font
        Me.ClientSize = New System.Drawing.Size(284, 261)
        Me.Controls.Add(Me.TableLayoutPanel1)
        Me.Name = "Form1"
        Me.Text = "Form1"
        Me.ResumeLayout(false)
        Me.PerformLayout

    End Sub
    Friend WithEvents TableLayoutPanel1 As System.Windows.Forms.TableLayoutPanel

End Class
```

Comment: Unusual request.  I suspect what you are *really* looking for is the TLP's MinimumSize property so it can't shrink too much.  If not then you'll have to add the code to flip the RowStyle.SizeType property between AutoSize and Absolute.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had originally tried @HansPassant's comments to no avail.  However, on writing code to attempt this again, I was successful, so I'm unsure what I was originally doing wrong.

As a result, this solution seems to do the trick, but if there's a better way to go about doing this, I'd be happy to hear it.

Full code is below:

> Form1.vb

```
Option Strict On
Option Explicit On
Option Infer Off

Public Class Form1
    Private Sub Form1_Load( sender As Object,  e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        TableLayoutPanel1.SuspendLayout()
        TableLayoutPanel1.Visible = False

        TableLayoutPanel1.RowStyles.Clear()

        For i As Integer = 0 To 2
            TableLayoutPanel1.RowStyles.Add(New RowStyle(SizeType.AutoSize))


            Dim c As New CheckBox()
            c.Text = "Checkbox" & i+1

            If i = 0
                AddHandler c.CheckedChanged,    Sub(sender2 As Object, e2 As EventArgs)
                                                    If TryCast(sender2, CheckBox).Checked
                                                        TryCast(TableLayoutPanel1.Controls(1), CheckBox).Visible = False
                                                    Else
                                                        TryCast(TableLayoutPanel1.Controls(1), CheckBox).Visible = True
                                                    End If
                                                End Sub
            End If

            TableLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(c, 0, i)
        Next

        TableLayoutPanel1.Visible = True

        TableLayoutPanel1.ResumeLayout()

        For i As Integer = 0 To TableLayoutPanel1.RowStyles.Count-1
            TableLayoutPanel1.RowStyles(i).SizeType = SizeType.Absolute
            TableLayoutPanel1.RowStyles(i).Height = TableLayoutPanel1.Controls(i).GetPreferredSize(New Size(0, 0)).Height + TableLayoutPanel1.Controls(i).Margin.Top + TableLayoutPanel1.Controls(i).Margin.Bottom
        Next
    End Sub
End Class
```

> Form1.Designer.vb

```
<Global.Microsoft.VisualBasic.CompilerServices.DesignerGenerated()> _
Partial Class Form1
    Inherits System.Windows.Forms.Form

    'Form overrides dispose to clean up the component list.
    <System.Diagnostics.DebuggerNonUserCode()> _
    Protected Overrides Sub Dispose(ByVal disposing As Boolean)
        Try
            If disposing AndAlso components IsNot Nothing Then
                components.Dispose()
            End If
        Finally
            MyBase.Dispose(disposing)
        End Try
    End Sub

    'Required by the Windows Form Designer
    Private components As System.ComponentModel.IContainer

    'NOTE: The following procedure is required by the Windows Form Designer
    'It can be modified using the Windows Form Designer.  
    'Do not modify it using the code editor.
    <System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThrough()> _
    Private Sub InitializeComponent()
        Me.TableLayoutPanel1 = New System.Windows.Forms.TableLayoutPanel()
        Me.SuspendLayout
        '
        'TableLayoutPanel1
        '
        Me.TableLayoutPanel1.AutoSize = True
        Me.TableLayoutPanel1.AutoSizeMode = System.Windows.Forms.AutoSizeMode.GrowAndShrink
        Me.TableLayoutPanel1.ColumnCount = 1
        Me.TableLayoutPanel1.Location = New System.Drawing.Point(13, 13)
        Me.TableLayoutPanel1.Name = "TableLayoutPanel1"
        Me.TableLayoutPanel1.RowCount = 1
        Me.TableLayoutPanel1.Size = New System.Drawing.Size(0, 0)
        Me.TableLayoutPanel1.TabIndex = 0
        '
        'Form1
        '
        Me.AutoScaleDimensions = New System.Drawing.SizeF(6!, 13!)
        Me.AutoScaleMode = System.Windows.Forms.AutoScaleMode.Font
        Me.ClientSize = New System.Drawing.Size(284, 261)
        Me.Controls.Add(Me.TableLayoutPanel1)
        Me.Name = "Form1"
        Me.Text = "Form1"
        Me.ResumeLayout(false)
        Me.PerformLayout

End Sub
    Friend WithEvents TableLayoutPanel1 As System.Windows.Forms.TableLayoutPanel

End Class
```